# how to pass file as argument in python script using argparse module?

Tags: python, argparse

I am writing an automation script in python using argparse module in which I want to use the -s as an option which takes file/file path as an argument. Can somebody help me to do this?

Example: ./argtest.py -s /home/test/hello.txt

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the module yet? It includes examples of how to do this. Where did you get stuck when you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="My program!", formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument("-s", type=argparse.FileType('r'), help="Filename to be passed")
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

open_file = args.s
```

If you want to open the file for writing, just change `r` to `w` in `type=argparse.FileType('r')`.  You could also change it to `a`, `r+`, `w+`, etc.

Comment: I  would omit the `nargs=1`; the default `nargs` value is usually better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import argparse

parse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parse.add_argument("-s")
args = parse.parse_args()
# print argument of -s
print('argument: ',args.s)
```

Suppose the above code is stored in the file `example.py`

```
$ python example.py -s /home/test/hello.txt
argument: /home/test/hello.txt
```

You can click [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/argparse.html)(Python3.x) or [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/argparse.html)(Python2.x) to learn more.

Comment: Hi zondo, I used your code but it throws me an error like "AttributeError: 'dict' has no attribute 's'. Kindly help

Comment: @AlaguJeeva - Try use `python-3.x`